# Building a kernel module

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to build a custom kernel. My requirement is to remove a driver that is built as a built in (boot time) module and make it as loadable module.

So I ran

```
make menuconfig
```

I went to the respective entry with <> braces. It is already marked as M, which is marked as module. When I built the kernel, the driver is already part of the kernel.

Hence removed the M option and made it as blank. Now when I built the kernel it is not part of the boot image. However when I tried to build the module separately, it didn't build as it is not part of the .config file (entry is commented out). I am missing a simple thing, yet I am unable to find that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your .config (just grep the driver not entire .config)

Comment: WHAT driver could be a relevant piece of information!

Comment: Is that driver a dependency of a built-in module?